# Is it bad practice to have a View Model with methods in it that fill the View Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

For a .Net MVC application, is it bad practice to have a View Model with methods in it that fill the View Model such as this -

```
public class MyViewModelClass
{
   public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
   public string MyProperty2 { get; set; }
   public string GetProperties()
   {
       this.MyProperty1 = DataRetriever.GetProperty1();
       this.MyProperty2 = DataRetriever.GetProperty2();

   }
}
```

Can this cause problems in MVC such as with posting from the view?

Comment: A controller should retrieve data from the model. A viewmodel should only be used to _transport_ the data.

Comment: Thanks, ZippV. Is there any reason in particular for your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is considered bad practice. A view model should be a [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) that contains no logic but only *transport* data

Comment: be sure to comment or provide a better answer when down voting, dear frenger